# plotting with meshgrid and imshow

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

Imshow and meshgrid are not working the way I thought. I have some function defined for a given (x,y) point in 2D that returns a scalar f(x,y). I want to visualize the function f using imshow.

```
x = np.linspace(0,4)
y = np.linspace(0,1)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.zeros((50,50))

for i in range(50):
   for j in range(50):
       Z[i,j] = f(X[i,j],Y[i,j])

fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(Z,extent=[0,4,1,0])
plt.show()
```

This works as expected except in the extent I think it should be [0,4,0,1]... Am I defining the Z[i,j] to each (x,y) pair incorrectly? An explanation for how this works would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I am aware, the `imshow` is normally used to display an image. The extent is then used to define how large it should be, say you might want to give an image as the background of the plot.

Instead I think you will find it more intuitive to use `pcolor` (demo [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/pcolor_demo.html#comparing-pcolor-with-similar-functions)). It works much the same as `imshow` so you can just supply `Z`. However, you can also give it the `X` and `Y` arrays. This way you can really check if your supplying the values correctly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,4)
y = np.linspace(0,1)

def f(x, y):
    return y * np.sin(x) 

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = np.zeros((50,50))

for i in range(50):
   for j in range(50):
       Z[i,j] = f(X[i,j],Y[i,j])

plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

I have added a function to show it works. Note that if your function is able to handle numpy arrays you can replace the initialisation of `Z` and the nested for loops with

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = f(X, Y)
```

This is cleaner and will be faster to compute.

Comment: Thanks-- I was not aware of this function. I like how pcolor provides extra information: the resolution of the grid since each box is the same, uniform color, unlike in imshow where it appears some smoothing is going on.

Comment: `pcolor` gets slow for large arrays... consider `pcolormesh` if your arrays are large and regular.